# Docker Containers not accessible outside of LAN

Tags: networking, docker, nginx

**Overview:**

I have Docker running several containers on an rack server running Ubuntu Server 18.04. Most of these containers provide a service that is accessible through a browser on a port other than 80. I setup a nginx container to provide the reverse proxy such that when I type ***service1.mydomain.com*** it will pass the request to the ip+port combination that hosts that service (the service is another docker container).

This works great from within my LAN. On any computer in my house I can type ***service.mydomain.com*** and have access to the container. I own mydomain and have DynamicDNS setup and ports 80 and 443 forwarded to the IP that nginx is running on.

**Problem:**

When I setup the containers to run on a macvlan network, I can access the services from outside of my LAN (at work, on my phone, etc). However, when I use the default Docker bridge network, the outside access is broken. I can still connect to the containers from within my house (LAN) but can no longer connect from outside my house.

**Troubleshooting:**

This is what I have tried to troubleshoot so far.

- Ran tcpdump at server.  Can see packets destined for the docker's ip:port combination.

  - If I make a request from within the LAN, I get a [S] flag followed by an [S.] flag and the request goes through.
  - If I make a request from outside the LAN, I get a bunch of [S] flags with the request not going through.  Seems like the packet is getting dropped somewhere in the server.
- Disabled UFW.  Did not help.
- Using netstat -i, there was no change in RX-DRP packets but increases in RX-OK packets to docker0 and eno2 interfaces.  There was an increase in TX-OK packets from docker0 but not eno2.  (nginx is using the IP of eno2)

Any ideas? I have been searching for days and cannot find any example of this issue.

Comment: What sort of troubleshooting have you done so far? Your question is probably missing some details that may be used to solve this issue.

Comment: @AulisRonkainen thanks for the quick reply.  I am going to update my question with troubleshooting info